# Ajax POST con django retorna siempre ERROR

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, post

**Buenas!** *seré conciso, tengo apenas 5 meses en el estudio del desarrollo, creo ser "nuevo", hay cosas que desconozco:*
Tengo que una petición Ajax para enviar información desde JavaScript/HTML hasta Django, puedo captar CORRECTAMENTE la información desde Django y almacenarla, pero no logro retornar un success por parte de Ajax, intente muchas cosas y SIEMPRE tira error :(

> **¿debo realizar otra petición porque el post solo envía la información y no se puede recibir?**
> **¿deberia utilizar algunas funciones asincronicas ademas de ajax, con django de por medio?**
> **No se me ocurren soluciones.**

lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
function ajaxSelect(userTo,message){
$.ajax({
    headers:{"X-CSRFToken":csrftoken},
    url:"/chat/",
    type:"POST",
    data:{"userTo":userTo, 'message':message},
    dataType:"json",
    success:(response)=>{   
        console.log("working perfectly");
        console.log(response)  
    },
    error:(error)=>{
        console.log("algo fallo...")
        console.log(error);
    }
})}
```

---

Este es mi C.B View de django.

---

```
class chat(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'view.html'
form_class = addMessage

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs) 
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_active:
        pass
    else:
        return None
    context['usr'] = User.objects.exclude(username=self.request.user)
    context['chat'] = userChat.objects.filter(userFrom=self.request.user)
    return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)

def ajaxResponse(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    query = userChat.objects.last().toJSON()
    print(query)
    if self.request.headers.get('x-requested-with')=='XMLHttpRequest':
        return JsonResponse(query, safe=False)


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form(self.get_form_class())
    if request.POST['message']=="":
        return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form, **kwargs)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)
    

def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    print("Se agrego correctamente ese form...")
    form.instance.userFrom = self.request.user
    # print(form.cleaned_data)
    form.save()
    self.ajaxResponse(self, self.request)
    return render(self.request, self.template_name)
```

Aunque no le vea mucho sentido, incluyo la imagen del Ajax, devolviendo el "error" en vez del success:
[image: ...]

Answer (score 0):

Dejare esta respuesta, unos dias despues logre solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

Originalmente, desde Django, en el método `ajaxResponse()` devolvía el contexto retornando un  `JsonResponse()` hacia ajax.
Este ultimo método estaba dando errores que no eran notificados, asi que opte por sustituirlo por las siguientes tres lineas, serializando el contexto antes:

```
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    CONTEXT = json_serializer.serialize(CONTEXT)
    return HttpResponse(CONTEXT, 'application/json')
```

Si alguien tiene una solución mas fácil, le agradezco.